# Show that $|A_k|\ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition, lu-decomposition

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ invertible matrix such that $A=L U$, where $L$ is a unit lower triangular matrix and $U$ is an upper triangular matrix. For $1 \leq k \leq n$, let $A_k$ denote the principal leading submatrix of $A$ formed by the first $k$ rows and the first $k$ columns of $A$. Show that $\det\left(A_{k}\right) \neq 0$, $k=1,2, \ldots, n$.

I just verified it by taking a matrix $A$ with real constant entities inside it and then finding $A_k$ using $A$ and I proved that determinant is not equal to $0$

But how can we do that in a more generalized way ? Just a little bit of steps showing may also work

Comment: Hint: Write both $L$ and $U$ as $2\times 2$ block matrices by splitting them after row $k$ and under column $k$. Observe that each of them has a zero block. Now multiply them in block form. What result do you get for $A_k$ ?

Comment: can u show some work. i will be higly obliged

Comment: i am not good at block matrices... is there any other way.... ? becuase i can visualise what u want to say. ? @darijgrinberg

Comment: My main point is that you should prove that $A_k = L_k U_k$, where $L_k$ and $U_k$ are the northwesternmost $k\times k$-submatrices of $L$ and $U$ (just as $A_k$ is the one of $A$). With block matrices you can prove this in your head; otherwise you have to recall the formula for the product of two matrices and mess with sums and indices a bit.

Comment: then we everytime gets $|A_k| = 1$ @darijgrinberg ?

Comment: Nope, because the diagonal entries of $U_k$ aren't usually $1$.

Comment: ohhh i got it .... thanks ... but they are some non zero values

Comment: Exactly. And $L_k$ and $U_k$ are triangular matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an invertible matrix such that it has an $LU$ factorization : $\,\,A=LU.$

Let $k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, and

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
A_k & * \\
* & *
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
L_k & 0 \\
* & *
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{pmatrix}
U_k & * \\
0 & *
\end{pmatrix},
$$

where $(*)$ indicates a block matrix that we don't need to keep track of.

By doing multiplication block by block, we obtain  $A_{k}=L_{k}\cdot U_{k}, \; \; $ and thus : $$\det(A_k)=\det(L_k)\det(U_k)=\det(U_k).$$

Since $\det(U)\neq 0$, then $\det(U_k)\neq 0$ (No coefficient in the diagonal of $U_k$ is zero).

Finally : $\boxed{\forall k \in \{1,\ldots,n\} : \det(A_k)\neq0.}$